# What does the "shuffle" parameter do in sklearn.datasets.make_blobs?

Tags: python, parameters, scikit-learn

Under the "shuffle" parameter in [**sklearn.datasets.make_blobs**](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_blobs.html), the provided description is "shuffle the samples." What does shuffling the samples mean and how is it different from not shuffling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From source code:

```
if shuffle:
    # Randomly permute samples
    X, y = util_shuffle(X, y, random_state=generator)

    # Randomly permute features
    indices = np.arange(n_features)
    generator.shuffle(indices)
    X[:, :] = X[:, indices]

return X, y
```

Meaning, that the generated samples returned by the function are not ordered by label   or some other criteria.

Comment: Thanks, just tested it out and it seems the difference is in ordering by label.